# Memoir: How to change appendix page name also in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, babel, appendix

I use the `memoir` class and want to change the title appearing on the so-called appendix page (the first part-like page which starts the appendices, realized by `\appendixpage`). This can be achieved with `\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{...}`. However, the table of contents still shows the default title "Appendices". (In particular, I want to rename the appendices title because the document is not in English. Choosing a language by using a package like `babel` apparently doesn't do much.)

**Question:** How can the appendices title be changed also for the table of contents? Thanks in advance!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anhänge}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Awesome chapter}

\begin{appendices}
\appendixpage
\chapter{Great appendix}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to also change the entry in the table of contents from "Appendices"  to "Anhänge", use `\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anhänge}`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anhänge}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anhänge}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Awesome chapter}

\begin{appendices}
\appendixpage
\chapter{Great appendix}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. That one was kind of obvious... sorry for the inconvenience. RTFM to myself then. ;)